# create UiImage for image in www/Images folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I need to use images present in `WWW/Images` folder in my cordova iOs project. I am using cordova-2.3.0 and iOs 6 versions.

I tried to get image by below code but it is not working for images in `WWW/Images` folder, it is working fine for images present in resources folder.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Car_Main.png"];
```

How can I access Images present in `WWW/Images` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't really understand, where is your WWW/Images folder. If in application directory - try this code.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingString:@"/WWW/Images/Car_Main.png"];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

If in project - maybe you forget to add your image to target resources?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Save from documents

NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/WWW/Images/Car_Main.png.png"];

BOOL Done = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path 
          contents:nil attributes:nil];

if (!Done) {
    NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", path);
} else {
    NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
   [myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage)];
   [myFileHandle closeFile];
}


// Get from documents

NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
UIImage* loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
```